# Need help remove inconsistent row

Tags: r, date

Please I have the following data frame.

From the data frame, my objective is to remove Intake that does not follow with 3 months. That is the difference between the intake date and that of 3 months should align.

The first loop code was used to generate d1, d2, d3 as shown below

```
for (i in 2:(length(MyPanelBMIn3[,"UIDhmis"]))) {  
if ((MyPanelBMIn3[i,"UIDhmis"]== MyPanelBMIn3[(i-1),"UIDhmis"]) &    MyPanelBMIn3[i, "Freq"] == MyPanelBMIn3[i-1, "Freq"]) {  
MyPanelBMIn3[i,"dd1"] <- MyPanelBMIn3[i,"Date2"]- MyPanelBMIn3[i-1, "Date2"]  
MyPanelBMIn3[i,"dd2"] <- MyPanelBMIn3[i,"Date2"]- MyPanelBMIn3[i+1, "Date2"]
MyPanelBMIn3[i,"dd3"] <- MyPanelBMIn3[i-1,"Date2"]- MyPanelBMIn3[i+1, "Date2"]    
} else 
if ((MyPanelBMIn3[i,"UIDhmis"]== MyPanelBMIn3[(i-1),"UIDhmis"]) & MyPanelBMIn3[i, "Freq"] != MyPanelBMIn3[i-1, "Freq"]){ 
 MyPanelBMIn3[i,"dd1"] <- MyPanelBMIn3[i,"Date2"]- MyPanelBMIn3[i-1, "Date2"]
 MyPanelBMIn3[i,"dd2"] <- MyPanelBMIn3[i,"Date2"]- MyPanelBMIn3[i+1,    "Date2"]
 }
 }
```

DATA:

```
    UIDhmis CID Freq    Date    Index   d1  d2  d3
1   100 Intake  22/09/2014  1   NA  NA  NA
1   100 Intake  16/04/2012  2   -889    -85 804
1   100 03 Month    10/07/2012  3   85  -84 NA
2   214 Intake  02/09/2013  1   NA  NA  NA
2   214 Intake  05/04/2013  2   -150    -241    -91
2   214 03 Month    02/12/2013  3   241 -90 NA
3   301 Intake  03/11/2015  1   NA  NA  NA
3   301 Intake  15/02/2015  2   -261    -359    -98
3   740 03 Month    09/02/2016  3   359 -6  NA
```

The code below was used to compare d1, d2 and d3 to be able to determine which line to drop between first and second "Intake", I encountered an error on absolute value as given below

```
for (i in 2:(length(MyPanelBMIn5[, "UIDhmis"]))) {
if ((MyPanelBMIn5[i, "UIDhmis"] == MyPanelBMIn5[(i-1), "UIDhmis"]) &         MyPanelBMIn5[i, "Freq"] == MyPanelBMIn5[(i-1), "Freq"] & abs(MyPanelBMIn5[i-1,   "d1"]) > 100 & abs(MyPanelBMIn5[i, "d2"])  <= 100 ) {
MyPanelBMIn6 <- with(MyPanelBMIn5, MyPanelBMIn5$UIDhmis != i-1)
}else 
if ((MyPanelBMIn5[i, "UIDhmis"] == MyPanelBMIn5[i+1, "UIDhmis"]) & MyPanelBMIn5[i, "Freq"] == MyPanelBMIn5[i+1, "Freq"] & abs(MyPanelBMIn5[i+1, "d1"]) < abs(MyPanelBMIn5[(i+1), "d2"])) {
  MyPanelBMIn6 <- with(MyPanelBMIn5, MyPanelBMIn5$UIDhmis != i)
}else if   
((MyPanelBMIn5[i, "UIDhmis"] == MyPanelBMIn5[(i+1), "UIDhmis"]) &           MyPanelBMIn5[i, "Freq"] == MyPanelBMIn5[(i+1), "Freq"] & abs(MyPanelBMIn5[i,  "d1"]) > 100 & abs(MyPanelBMIn5[i, "d2"]) > 100 & abs(MyPanelBMIn5[i, "d3"]) <= 100) {
  MyPanelBMIn6 <- with(MyPanelBMIn5, MyPanelBMIn5$UIDhmis != i)
}
}
```

Error Message:
Error in abs(MyPanelBMIn5[i - 1, "d1"]) : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function

The objective is to remove Intake that is not within 3 months to "03 Months". For example, I will like to remove line 1 from UIDhmis = 100 as this observation is far away from its "03 Months".

In  the UIDhmis = 214, the second "Intake" has to be removed as it is about five months to "03 Months" frequency.

Can someone help locate what my mistake is or show me how to do this better in R. I am using R version 3.3.2 with Window 7 Professional.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the row indices of all "03 Month" cases

```
rowids <- which(MyPanelBMIn5$CID == '03 Month')
```

Then create a vector including these rows as well as the rows before them

```
rowids <- c(rowids, rowids - 1)
```

Make sure each index is unique and greater than 0

```
rowids <- sort(unique(rowids))
rowids <- rowids[rowids > 0]
```

Then, subset your original dataset by this index

```
data_subset <- MyPanelBMIn6[rowids, ]
```